# Visual Studio setup project says build failed, but does not tell the reason why

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, dll, setup-project

```
------ Starting pre-build validation for project 'CServ Setup' ------ 
WARNING: All custom dialogs must precede the 'Installation Folder' dialog.
------ Pre-build validation for project 'CServ Setup' completed ------
1>------ Build started: Project: CServ Setup, Configuration: Release-W2k3 ------
Building file 'C:\temp\Backup Solution Sources\SQLite\CServ Setup\Release-W2k3\CServ     Setup.msi'...
WARNING: No 'HomeSite' attribute has been provided for 'Visual C++ Runtime Libraries (x86)', so the package will be published to the same location as the bootstrapper.
Packaging file 'MD5.dll'...
Packaging file 'Service Installer.exe'...
Packaging file 'Common.dll'...
Packaging file 'cygbz2-1.dll'...
Packaging file 'ConfigEditor.exe'...
Packaging file 'dr4qvb9h.pol'...
Packaging file 'crx86.dll'...
Packaging file 'cygwin1.dll'...
Packaging file 'CServ Service.exe'...
Packaging file 'cmx86.dll'...
Packaging file 'dtblcyrm.pol'...
Packaging file 'CServConfig.xml'...
Packaging file '6yixebcz.pol'...
Packaging file 'SocHandler.dll'...
Packaging file 'knj_y5bk.pol'...
Packaging file 'OServHandler.dll'...
Packaging file 'AdminConsoleInterface.dll'...
Packaging file 'cmx86.dll'...
Packaging file 'sc.exe'...
Packaging file 'TransferServer.dll'...
Packaging file 'cmx86.dll'...
Packaging file '7b0ouomo.mic'...
Packaging file 'StartCServ.exe'...
Packaging file 'HouseKeeper.dll'...
Packaging file 'crx86.dll'...
Packaging file 'Logger.dll'...
Packaging file 'cpx86.dll'...
Packaging file 'zip.exe'...
Packaging file 'Backup Solution Watchdog.exe'...
Packaging file 'ConfigurationHandler.dll'...
Packaging file 'cpx86.dll'...
Packaging file 'sqlite3.dll'...
Packaging file 'zlib1.dll'...
Packaging file 'cg2bqsbk.mic'...
Packaging file 'crx86.dll'...
Packaging file 'dr_73xog.mic'...
Packaging file 'CServHousekeeperConfig.xml'...
Packaging file 'CServLoggerConfig.xml'...
Packaging file 'CServ.dll'...
Packaging file 'cpx86.dll'...
Packaging file 'xerces-c_2_8.dll'...
Packaging file 'Scheduler.dll'...
Packaging file 'wuqeehyk.mic'...
Packaging file 'unzip.exe'...
Packaging file 'ufdprep.exe'...
Packaging file 'CompressionTool.dll'...
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 18 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

This is the output I get when I do a build on the setup project. Note that all the other files/outputs are from other projects within the same solution. How do I go about troubleshooting this?

Also, it creates the msi file, but when installed, application doesn't work right. The console program is missing a lot of cout statements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the 'Tools->Options' menu, 'Projects and Solutions->Build and Run' change the value of the 'MSBuild project build output verbosity' to Detailed or Diagnostic, should help you find the problem.

Comment: It was not building correctly because I had set Target to Win32 instead of any CPU.